# Override Default Save Method And Create Duplicate

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am looking to create a duplicate instance each time a user tries to update an instance. The existing record is untouched and the full update is saved to the new instance.

Some foreign keys and reverse foreign keys must also be duplicated. The Django documentation 
[talks about duplicating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances), but does not address reverse foreign keys.

Firstly, is there an accepted way of approaching this problem?

Secondly, I am unsure whether it's best to overwrite the form save method or the model save method? I would want it to apply to everything, regardless of the form, so I assume it should be applied at the model level?

A simplified version of the models are outlined below.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Line(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=4)
```

Comment: So what happens with the existing record that is untouched when the duplicate is saved?

Comment: Nothing happens to it. I may decide to include a flag to mark it as a prior version, but that probably won't be needed.

Comment: Could you include your models so we can see the relationships?

Comment: Sure –- I have just updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my shot at it. If you need it to duplicate every time you make any changes, then override the model `save` method. Note that this will not have any effect when executing `.update()` on a queryset.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=15)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            # if we dont have a pk set yet, it is the first time we are saving. Nothing to duplicate.
            super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # save the line items before we duplicate
            lines = list(self.line_set.all())

            self.pk = None
            super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

            for line in lines:
                line.pk = None
                line.invoice = self
                line.save()
```

This will create a duplicate `Invoice` every time you call `.save()` on an existing record. It will also create duplicates for every `Line` tied to that `Invoice`. You may need to do something similar every time you update a `Line` as well.

This of course is not very generic. This is specific to these 2 models. If you need something more generic, you could loop over every field, determine what kind of field it is, make needed duplicates, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. The only problem is that this doesn't work for lines that are being updated.

Comment: Do you want the invoice to duplicate every time a line is updated? That could be a little crazy if there are multiple lines.

Comment: Yes. The invoice has to duplicate every time a line is updated. There needs to be a full historical record.